# Hibernate oneToMany without mapping or joining

Tags: hibernate, jpa

Is it possible to add a list of Entitys into another Entity without having a mapping or joinColumn?

What I want is something like

```
EntityA{
@OneToMany
List<EntityX> allEntitiesX
}
```

This List should behave like

```
Query query=session.createQuery("from EntityX"); 
List allEntitiesX=query.list();
```

So if I load the EntiyA I also have acces to all other entities EntityX(with lazy-loading) without "leaving" EntityA. Due to our legacy programm I can not add a new table to connect both Entitys, because I would have to update all existing customer data and teach the old system to handle this joinTable the same way.

If possible beeing able to filter with conditions would be good aswell.

Why I want it:
In our system every "mainEntity" can have properties (EntityX). 
Every property entity has a list of values, and these values are mapped with a joinTable to the "mainEntity".
If I want to add a method setProperty(propertyName, value) I have the problem that I cant find the correct propertyEntity to add my value.
The setter would have to be moved to a place where I can do entityManager querys.

Comment: It is completely unclear what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

Yes that is possible but that will create another third table but you actually dont need third table in case of onetomany and manytoone as every row of EntityX will contain one column for EntityA.

The simplest mapping you can do is like below.

```
EntityA{
@OneToMany(mappedBy="entityA",cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
List<EntityX> allEntitiesX
}
```

And in another entity

```
EntityX{
@ManyToOne
EntityA entityA; 
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer, but I fear this will not help me because I reality it would be a manyToMany connection (but I need only one direction). Additionaly I cant change the tables because antothes non-JPA system is working on the same database. If the answer in this case is no I will mark this answer as Accepted

Comment: refer this http://websystique.com/hibernate/hibernate-many-to-many-unidirectional-annotation-example/